# Longest 'Random Non intersecting' path in a grid

Tags: algorithm, graph, longest-path

Given a grid size(`m*n`), how could one generate a random path between a start(`x1, y1`) and end(`x2, y2`) point with the added condition that the random path covers all the nodes

e.g.

- Grid of size 5*6
- Start Point -> (1, 1)
- End Point -> (1, 6)

What approach can be used to generate a random path that begins at (1, 1) and ends at (1, 6), plus the path travels through remaining 28 nodes?

Comment: Use a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to find every possible path (there are 397 between (1,1) and (1,6)). Then generate a random number between 0 and 396, and that's the path to choose. Note that some choices of start and end, e.g. (1,1) and (5,1), have no paths.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks, That is my approach currently. This is leading to some abnormally high run-times for higher dimension grids. I was hoping there would be another approach :). Appreciate your comment, at least, now I know I am not alone in thinking of this approach

Comment: Yup, I looked at this a little more today. Bottom line: the search space is huge, and the number of unique [Hamiltonian paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) is small. So although it's easy to find a Hamiltonian path through the grid (e.g. zig zag from left to right, then right to left), finding a path that looks random is not easy.

Comment: The issue is demonstrated by [this simple example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhGOF.png). Having followed the solid line to point (3,4), the only valid way forward is to follow the green dotted path. But a naive DFS could spend hours exploring paths that go down or right from the end of the solid path.